# Is a topological space isomorphic to some group?

Tags: general-topology, group-theory

I'm reading topology without tears to develop intuition before attempting Munkres. I noticed how similar a topological space was to a group in Abstract Algebra.

> **1.1.1 Definitions.** Let $X$ be a non-empty set. A set $\tau$ of subsets of $X$ is said to be a *topology* on $X$ if
>
> 1. $X$ and the empty set, $\varnothing$, belong to $\tau$,
> 2. the union of any (finite or infinite) number of sets in $\tau$ belongs to $\tau$, and
> 3. the intersection of any two sets in $\tau$ belongs to $\tau$.
>
> The pair $(X,\tau)$ is called a *topological space*.

Can you see why $X$ and $\varnothing$ behave like identities? And $\cup$ and $\cap$ are like binary operations. And this 'group' is closed under both operations.

Is there a group a topological space is isomorphic to? Or are these just coincidences?

Comment: It's a monoid, as others have written. If I'm not mistaken, then this also gives you a contravariant functor from $\mathbf{Top}$ to $\mathbf{Mon}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not in general. But you're not *too* far from the truth.<sup>1</sup>

Generally, if $X$ is a set, then $\mathcal P(X)$ is a group using symmetric difference as a commutative addition operator. It's even a ring when using $\cap$ for multiplication.

But in the case of $\cap$ and $\cup$ as candidates for addition we run into some problems, since neither is reversible. Namely, $A\cup B=A\cup C$ does not imply that $B=C$, which means that there is no additive inverse.

We can try and argue with symmetric difference again; but a topology need not be closed under symmetric differences, e.g. $(-1,1)\mathbin\triangle(0,1)=(-1,0]$, and the latter is not open in the standard topology of $\Bbb R$.

---

1. Note, by the way, that a group is a set with an operation on that set. Like $\Bbb Z$ with $+$. Whereas a topological space is a set with a *collection of subsets*, rather than an operation.

   I took the liberty of understanding the question a bit differently. If $\tau$, the topology itself, is a group.

Answer (score 9):

The system $(\tau, \cap)$ forms a *monoid* with identity $X$, and $(\tau, \cup)$ forms a monoid with identity $\emptyset$.

A monoid is an associative binary operation with identity; the inverse axiom is excluded. Note, for example, that for $S \in \tau$ nonempty, there can be no $T \in \tau$ such that $S \cup T = \emptyset$, because $S \cup T \supset S \supsetneq \emptyset$.